# When using Spring-Cloud-Sleuth, are we getting parentSpanID for free when doing across microservice calls?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am working on integrate Spring-Cloud-Sleuth to our microservices, and I notice that Sleuth supports parentSpanId concept, are we getting this for free when we do cross microservices calls? Do we have to have some special setup to get this function working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that value is propagated further on. You don't need to do any additional configuration of Spring Cloud Sleuth,